# Viber bathroom mirror light replacement

Tags: bathroom, mirror, halogen, light

I own a Viber bathroom mirror that houses some halogen lights at the top.  Does anyone know how I might replace the bulbs on such a unit?  They don't appear to twist, push or pull, and I can't see any obvious releases.

[image: from the front]
[image: From the top]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

There was a super-simple solution - there was a cap on the underside that you just pry off with a knife, as per a similar set of instructions [here](http://www.roperrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/RRM-MIR-MSC-CSC-Canopy-7008001000.pdf)

[image]